# Flutter How to update widgets one after the other instead of at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the function update_list to change the values in the list when it is called. And then I want it to change the text in the column.

That works, but now I want the first value to change (and to see the new value on the screen) and then a second later the next value and so on. But with my code it changes all together at the end.

How can I make the values change one after the other and not all at once?

```
class class_one extends StatefulWidget {
      const class_one({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      State<class_one> createState() => _class_oneState();
    }

    class _class_oneState extends State<class_one> {
      List list = [0,1,2,3];

      void update_list(){
        setState((){
          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            list[i]=list[i]+10;
            sleep(Duration(seconds: 1));
          }
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('${list[0]}'),
              Text('${list[1]}'),
              Text('${list[2]}'),
              Text('${list[3]}'),
              GestureDetector(onTap: (){update_list();},child: Container(color: Colors.red,child: Text("next"),),)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use two solution for this issue:
**1**: use streaming mechanism(actually use from streamBuilder widget).
**2**:

```
void update_list() async{
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        setState((){
           list[i]=list[i]+10;

        });
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      }
  }
```

Comment: 1) I have never used the streaming mechanism before, do you may have a simple example for my problem?
2) I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me (in the list the value changes, but on the screen you don't see the new value yet).

Comment: 1)https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-streambuilder-widget-examples

2)It must work! I tested it, pay attention to my code

Comment: 1) thanks 2)Strange, I copied and pasted your code but the values still change all at the same time...

Comment: 1) welcome 2) oh no excuse me, you should not use sleep! Because it puts the main thread to sleep and you can't see changes, see my code edited